# Fetch a value by traversing backwards until a pattern is found in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe structure as below:

| _c0 | _c1 | _c2 | _c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Open scheme | null | null | null |
| Ad | null | null | null |
| 119551 | INF209KA12Z1 | INF209KA13Z9 | Ad |
| 119552 | INF209MK12Z1 | INF209MKA13Z9 | Ad |
| Closed scheme | null | null | null |
| Ad | null | null | null |
| 119553 | INF209KA12aZ1 | INF209KAd13Z9 | Ad |
| 119554 | INF209MK12Zs1 | INF209MKAd13Z9 | Ad |

For all the rows falling between **open scheme** and **closed scheme**, i want to append the *Open scheme* value as new column , similarly for the rows after **closed scheme** , i want to append the *closed scheme* as new value, to identify rows having open scheme and rows having closed scheme.

Expected output :

| _c0 | _c1 | _c2 | _c3 | scheme type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Open scheme | null | null | null | null |
| Ad | null | null | null | null |
| 119551 | INF209KA12Z1 | INF209KA13Z9 | Ad | **Open scheme** |
| 119552 | INF209MK12Z1 | INF209MKA13Z9 | Ad | **Open scheme** |
| Closed scheme | null | null | null | null |
| Ad | null | null | null | null |
| 119553 | INF209KA12aZ1 | INF209KAd13Z9 | Ad | **closed scheme** |
| 119554 | INF209MK12Zs1 | INF209MKAd13Z9 | Ad | **closed scheme** |

I thought of using lag with unbounded preceding i.e. traversing backwards till i find a _c0 column value with matching keyword as *scheme* but not getting how can i add such criteria in lag function

Please suggest if there is any way in pyspark to get rows before a line having a specific pattern.

Comment: Needs more info: What are grouping rules? For ex, if there are multiple occurrences of `Open` and `Closed` events, then how to order and group them?

Comment: For the column _c0, there will be only one occurance of scheme type, basically the scheme type is kind of a header and then there are schemes mentioned in next row(s). Again when new schemes under new category are shown in similar fashion.